# Get current route segment from Route type using ArcGIS Runtime LocationListener?

Tags: routing, route, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to get the route segment on which I am currently navigating. i.e. I want to get the current route segment when `onLocationChanged` method of my `LocationListener` is called. A route is constituted from small segments. And we have the routing directions related to a segment but I do not know how to get the current segment in my `LocationListener`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `RouteDirections` you can compare the maneuver geometry returned from `RouteDirection.getGeometry()` and the point returned from `onLocationChanged()` by using one of the `GeometryEngine` methods that return a `Proximity2DResult`, e.g. `GeometryEngine.getNearestVertex(Geometry, Point);`.